# Как редактировать программу в IDLE?

Tags: python, linux, idle

Начал самостоятельно изучать Питон. Как в IDLE исправлять ошибки после выхода синтаксической ошибки? Неужели все переписывать?

Comment: copy paste

Answer (score 4):

Так вы скрипты создавайте =) (создание: File - New window, запуск скрипта: Run - Run module)

А интерактивный интерпретатор - полезная вещь, но не для этого.

Если просто ошибка в команде, то можете её перенабрать правильно - окружение, все переменные и всё прочее сохраняются.

Пример:

```
a = 1 # результат не отображается
a + 2 # выводит 3
a + b # NameError: name 'b' is not defined
b = 2 # результат не отображается
a + b # выводит 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте себе какой-нибудь редактор типа Aptana или Geany. Ну, а если есть время, то советую попробывать vim, но он не прост в настройке.

Answer (score -1):

Если набиваешь команды непосредственно в IDLE то просто копируешь команду выше и исправляешь ошибку, а лучше пиши сразу в виде программы, тогда просто открываешь её и правишь.

Comment: Извините, но поясните, что новго даёт ваш ответ в дополнение к уже существующим?